# Hiding UIButton if variable has certain value?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to hide a `UIButton` as long as a certain variable has not reached a certain value.

I tried some `setHidden` and `isHidden` setups, but I guess I did it all wrong. I don't exactly know where to put these commands.

I have looked for a solution at almost every webpage but I got no idea what everybody is talking about.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let startvalue = 1000000

    @IBOutlet weak var Counter: UITextField!
    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if number > 1{
            number -= 1
            Counter.text = String(number)
        } else {
            Counter.text = "Hurray"
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Reset: UIButton!
    @IBAction func Reset(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if number == 1{
            number = startvalue
            Counter.text = String (number)

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     var number = startvalue {
        didSet {
           if number < 1 {
           Reset.isHidden = false
           }
       }
    }

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

I don't now what I need to put where to hide `Result` as long as `number` is greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Handle it in the `didSet` of the variable.

```
var number = startValue {
    didSet {
        if number < 1 {
            yourButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever your `number` is changed, the `didSet` block will check if the value is less than 1. If so, it'll unhide the button.

**Note:** Make sure the button is hidden before the view shows. Also, make sure to hide the button if needed on resetting.

---

Use *lowerCamelCase* for variable names like they say in the API design [guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

Comment: Thx, but I now have the following alerts: Use of unsolved identifier 'Reset' (the buttons name)

Comment: @Eleips have you not declared your button in the class?

Comment: I guess I did declare it...(Take a look at the original problem above the 'problem' marking):    @IBAction func Reset(_ sender: UIButton) {...}

Comment: @Eleips that is the button action. That doesn't give you an instance of the button to work with outside of that method. You should be having an @IBOutlet for the button in your storyboard and use that in your `didSet`. Like how you have an outlet of your textfield!

Comment: I did the following: @IBOutlet weak var Reset: UIButton! even connected it to the Button in the Main.storyboard via control+drag, but it still mentions Reset to be an unresolved identifier

Comment: @Eleips can you update your question showing the code without breaks for text and proper indentation?

Comment: @Eleips well your number is a global variable and your button is outside it's scope. Move the code inside your class and it will work fine. Any reason it is global?

Comment: OK, that worked fine and there is no error left, but how do I declare the button to be hidden from start on/ before view shows and how to reset it to be hidden after pressing Reset?

Comment: @Eleips change your `var number = ...` to `lazy var number =...` (or) don't initialize it and set it in `viewDidLoad` or `init`. Please go through the Swift language guide once. It'll significantly speed your progress IMO :)

Comment: I moved `let start value = 1000000` back to being global and that made the error disappear...I guess I better start reading this guide, I tried to learn with SoloLearn, but that seems to be the wrong way :)

Comment: after moving it into `viewDidLoad` it tells `number` was an unresolved identifier. Thanks a lot for your patience with an idiot like me...

Comment: @Eleips please read and understand what is being said carefully. I said _initialize_ the value in `viewDidLoad` or `init`, whichever you logic demands. Or change the variable to be `lazy`. Coding is not moving code here and there. There is logic. Be patient and take the time to understand why something works and something doesn't. Don't move code without understanding why. This is why i suggested you read the Swift book first. It should make it a whole lot easier for you to understand why those errors show up in the first place. :)

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I need to understand what I am doing to continue and right now I am not. I will read that book and if some day I am able to publish any app I will put you in the credits as a mentor making me think serious about coding if that was okay for you. You helped a lot even though it feels like being no step further than at the beginning. I always liked logic constructs and math has fascinated me a lot, but I guess I just need to climb up the ladder to continue.

Comment: @Eleips haha. That is a really good attitude you have. You will get far with that attitude :) Good luck.